# Getting Local Storage to Remember addClass

Tags: local-storage, addclass

I'm trying to get local storage to remember when an item is clicked... basically works like a toggle and i want it to remember when you click or show one of the boxes.  It looks like it's recording it in the console but when you reload the page it goes back to original? What am i doing wrong?  I want it to remember when a box goes from red to green.

Here's my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/AafAN/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="modalbox">  
    <div class="token complete-sm-off">click me</div>
    <div class="token complete-med-off"></div>
    <div class="token complete-lrg-off"></div>

<button id="clear">Clear </button>

</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".complete-sm-off").click(function(){

      $completedToken.addClass("complete-sm-on");

 });


var $completedToken = $(".complete-sm-off");

// On ALT+L event
if ($completedToken.hasClass("complete-sm-on")) {
    $completedToken.addClass("complete-sm-on");
    window.localStorage.hasLightClass = true;
} else {
    window.localStorage.hasLightClass = false;
    $completedToken.removeClass("complete-sm-on");
}
for (var key in localStorage) {
    console.log(key + ": " + localStorage[key]);
}
// On page load
var hasClass = window.localStorage.hasLightClass || false;
if (JSON.parse(hasClass)) {
  $completedToken.addClass("complete-sm-on");
}   




//clear local storage button
$("#clear").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     window.localStorage.clear();

  });
```

CSS:

```
.token {
    background-image:url(imgs/token_checkmarks_042813.png);
    width:80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;
    }
.complete-sm-off{background-color:red; opacity:0.5;      }
.complete-med-off{background-color:red; opacity:0.5;      }
.complete-lrg-off{background-color:red; opacity:0.5;     }

 .complete-sm-on{background-color:green;  opacity: 1;}
 .complete-med-on{background-color:green;  opacity: 1;}
 .complete-lrg-on{background-color:green;  opacity: 1;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after some research...

When the quiz is complete... set the token item like this:

```
 $(".myItem").click(function(){
localStorage.setItem('mySmallTokenState', 'open');
});
```

Put this in your document ready tag. This checks to see if the item is in local storage with the page is loaded.  If so, add the completed class.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){   


    if(localStorage.getItem('mySmallTokenState') == 'open') {
                               //add class with completed token
                $(".complete-sm-off").addClass("complete-sm-on");


    }


 });
```